# How to achieve numpy indexing with xarray Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I know the x and the y indices of a 2D array (numpy indexing).

Following this [documentation](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#positional-indexing), xarray uses e.g. Fortran style of indexing.

So when I pass e.g.

```
ind_x = [1, 2]
ind_y = [3, 4]
```

I expect 2 values for the index pairs (1,3) and (2,4), but xarray returns a 2x2 matrix.

Now I want to know how to achieve numpy like indexing with xarray?

Note:  I want to avoid loading the whole data into memory. So using `.values` api is not part of the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? If you don't want to "load the whole data into memory" I'm assuming you are working with dask based xarrays?

Comment: As I understand xarray correctly It just loads headers of a netcdf into memory. Dask is used to apply functions to big datasets because it processes only chunks of the data, I think.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the dask use-case. Of course, performance will be strongly dependent on how the data itself is stored, and how the dask chunking is set up in relation to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the underlying `numpy` array to index it directly:

```py
import xarray as xr

x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

ind_x = [1, 2]
ind_y = [3, 4]

print(x.air.data[0, ind_y, ind_x].shape)
# (2,)
```

**Edit:**

Assuming you have your data in a `dask`-backed `xarray` and don't want to load all of it into memory, you need to use `vindex` on the `dask` array behind the `xarray` data object:

```py
import xarray as xr

# simple chunk to convert to dask array
x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature").chunk({"time":1})

extract = x.air.data.vindex[0, ind_y, ind_x]

print(extract.shape)
# (2,)

print(extract.compute())
# [267.1, 274.1], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the question. This solution is pretty nice for small batches of data. But I want to access thousands of files and want to avoid loading data into memory. So I need to use indexing tools from xarray itself.

Comment: That looks quite good. But do you know If xarray loads all data into memory when not using xarray+dask? Because netcdf4 library does https://annefou.github.io/metos_python/07-LargeFiles/

Comment: It'll only load the data required for the analysis if possible (e.g. if the underlying datatype allows that - I have no idea how netcdf handles this). That's why the "best practice" for these workflows is to load the data as dask array, reduce and only compute it in the end. Of course there are exceptions (e.g. repeated tasks on the same data) where you might want to `persist` the data beforehand

Comment: Using netcdf4 library is 6 times faster than using xarray+Dask .

Comment: @dl.meteo while this will depend on the usecase, xarray+Dask might not be superfast out of the box. But if properly configured, it can be extremely fast, and more important extremely scaleable. But this exceeds the extent of this question. You've asked "How to achieve numpy indexing with xarray Dataset" - I've pointed out two ways to do it. If that answers you question, please consider accepting my solution.

Comment: Totally right. Actually I am not able to use `open_mfdataset()` with multiple 2D arrays (lat, and lon as dimensions). I just want to stack them along a new (3rd) axis but I can't find a solution or example in the web.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take the speed into account I have made a test with different methods.

```
def method_1(file_paths: List[Path], indices) -> List[np.array]:
    data=[]
    for file in file_paths:
        d = Dataset(file, 'r')
        data.append(d.variables['hrv'][indices])
        d.close()
    return data


def method_2(file_paths: List[Path], indices) -> List[np.array]:
    data=[]
    for file in file_paths:
        data.append(xarray.open_dataset(file, engine='h5netcdf').hrv.values[indices])
    return data


def method_3(file_paths: List[Path], indices) -> List[np.array]:
    data=[]
    for file in file_paths:
        data.append(xarray.open_mfdataset([file], engine='h5netcdf').hrv.data.vindex[indices].compute())
    return data
```

```
In [1]: len(file_paths)
Out[1]: 4813
```

The results:

- method_1 (using netcdf4 library): 101.9s
- method_2 (using xarray and values API): 591.4s
- method_3 (using xarray+dask): 688.7s

I guess that xarray+dask takes to much time within `.compute` step.

Comment: If you want to use dask, I highly recommend [checking out the docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/). In your specific example, you're calling `.compute` inside a loop which is generally a bad practice, so I'm not surprised that dask performs below expectations.

Comment: This is why I try to open all the files with `open_mfdataset` before but there is no further explanation of how to stack 2D arrays along a new axis in the doc  http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html . I know I have to define `concat_dims` parameter but there is no information how.